# SQL Server : concatenate and where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to concatenate three columns from two tables `Customer` and `Invoice`, create a new column and find the new_id member whose name begins from 'Astridgruber' in SQl Server.

The below is causing an error.

```
select 
    concat(c.FirstName, c.LastName, i.InvoiceId) as New_Id
from 
    Invoice i, Customer c
where 
    i.[CustomerId] = c.CustomerId 
where 
    New_Id = 'AstriGruber%'
```

Help will be much appreciated.

These are the tables from the Chinook Database:

[image]

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: If you are following a tutorial from SQLite, then you should be using their database engine to avoid issues with incompatible sql dialects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too long for a comment. You have a few issues:

1. You should be using modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax, not comma joins;
2. Too many `WHERE` clauses; `AND` the conditions together;
3. You can't use aliases in `WHERE` clauses; replace `New_Id` with `concat(c.FirstName,c.LastName,i.InvoiceId)`;
4. You should be using `LIKE`, not `=`

All up your query should look like:

```
select concat(c.FirstName,c.LastName,i.InvoiceId) as New_Id
from Invoice i
join Customer c on i.CustomerId = c.CustomerId 
where concat(c.FirstName,c.LastName,i.InvoiceId) LIKE 'AstriGruber%'
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=8b3c0095a971e96278eeffe02a04202d)